# How to add global syntax highlight in nano

Tags: nano, syntax-highlighting

I use nano as my text editor for development, so I would want trailing spaces to be highlighted.
Right now I am just adding the line:

```
color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"
```

to all the files included on my `.nanorc`.

But I want to add that line *directly* on my `.nanorc`.

Apparently you can't have `color` commands without a `syntax`, but I want that to apply to *all* syntaxes.

How do I do this?